# Prove $V$ is isomorphic to $ V^{2} $ as vector space where $ V=F[x] $ for some field F

Tags: linear-algebra

Proof: define g from $V$ to $ V^{2}$ by $ g(f(x)) =(f(x), f(x))$  then $g $ is linear and injective but cannot prove surjective. How can  I prove surjectiveness.

Edit : if g can't prove surjective then how can I prove isomorphism between $V$ and $V^{2} $ ? If you give an isomorphism then kindly give one such .

Comment: Not every function is of that form.. take for instance $(x, x^2)\in V^2$.

Comment: Then what should be the map g?

Comment: @Prandip : The only question in this Question is "How can I prove surjectiveness [?]".  You can't.  Do you have more to edit into your Question?

Comment: You can't prove it, since all you obtain is the diagonal of $V^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  even and odd.  The interesting thing to check is scalar multiplication (by an element of $F[x]$).

Comment: Even and odd? I did not get this. Kindly explain little more

Comment: Do you know what even and odd mean when talking about polynomials, or more simply, monomials?

Comment: No, tell me plz

Comment: An odd polynomial is one that is composed only of odd powers, i.e. $x$, $x^3$, $x^5$ ..., and an even polynomial is composed of $1$, $x^2$, $x^4$ .... . Another useful fact is that any polynomial can be broken into even and odd parts.

Comment: @EricTowers: I had assumed that the scalars were elements of $F$ in this case, not $F[x]$. If you've got the same map in mind that I do (call it $T$), then I don't think e.g. $x\cdot T[x] = T[x\cdot x]$.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC : OP doesn't specify the scalars of $V$ and $V^2$, but ... Since $F[x]$ contains no multiplicative inverse of $x$, $F[x]$ is not a field.  Consequently, there is a free module over $F[x]$, but no vector space.   It is only sensible that $V$ and $V^2$ are vector spaces over $F$.